# Spring security - Only CSRF, no authentication required (using XML Configuration)

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I want to implement spring security using the XML configuration (version 4.0) , My application does not require authentication, only the thing that i need is CSRF prevention.

I have referred to the following

> [No Authentication and authorization using Spring Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29138483/no-authentication-and-authorization-using-spring-security)
>   But this is Java Configuration

my spring-security.xml looks like this

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">

<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll"/>
</http>
```

But i keep getting this error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager'
```

as there is no authentication manager defined.

Comment: I think you have to make a config bean that points to this

Comment: Can you please elaborate ? You mean a config bean for authentication manager? Should that bean be empty?

Comment: Please read [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.3.RELEASE/guides/html5/helloworld-xml.html)

Comment: Yeah i already saw that but how does it help

Comment: Auto configure obey you to do with.

Comment: is there any other config that will allow me to not have an authentication manager?

Comment: `auto-config="true"` adds a login form, basic authentication and logout URL. Given that you do not need these, you should remove it from your configuration. If you are using Spring Security 4.0 or higher, CSRF protection is enabled by default, so no special configuration is required for it beyond what you have already (once you have removed `auto-config`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @manish, the culprit was `auto-config="true"`. Removing it solved the issue.